# python while loop user input

Tags: python, while-loop

Write a program that keeps asking the user for numbers until they enter a non-number.

This is what I have now, it seems I have created an infinite loop.

```
i = 0
count = 0
while i != (int):
    i = input("Enter a number: ")
```

Comment: yes, you need to think of an input you can use to signal your intent to break out of the loop. Also, I think you need to use raw_input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.isdigit` method ,Note that if you are in python 2 you need to use `raw_input` because `isdigit()` is a string method :

```
i='0'
count = 0
while i.isdigit():
    i = input("Enter a number: ")
```

in python 2 :

```
i='0'
count = 0
while i.isdigit():
    i = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
```

Comment: Same method as mine, please change this and I will change my vote. Also i is not defined in this sense.

Comment: Nothing is wrong now, but at the time of my comment `i` was not defined and you had a totally different method of doing it at the time of my answer, and then when my answer came along you quick changed your method of solving the question

Answer (score 1):

You could ask for a number, and then check if the string entered is a digit using the built in [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method. Currently your code does not ask for a digit to be entered, it just uses 0 automatically. It would not account for a user entering a non-number the very first time.

```
i = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
while i.isdigit():
    i = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
```